# CSS grid - Animating content placement

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I have a 2x2 grid that contains three divs: `#blue` (2x1), `#red` (1x1) and `#yellow` (1x1) (**see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/y1qsg5eu/42/)**). This is what the grid looks like initially:

[image]

**NOTE: `#red` is overlapped by `#blue` and hence not visible.** To make it visible, the user must click `Show`. This is what the grid looks like after `Show` has been clicked:

[image]

In my current setup, clicking the `Show` button adds the `.expanded` class to `#red`, which changes the line placement of `#red` from `grid-column: 1/2` to `grid-column: 1/span2` and makes `#red` visible.
This works fine, however, I don't like the abruptness of the change and would like to give `#red` the appearance of sliding out from under `#blue` when `Show` is clicked. The problem is that since `grid-column` has a discrete animation type, it cannot be tween-transitioned in the way that a continuous property like `width` can.

**My attempt at a work-around:**

I tried specifying a `width` property for `#red`. It is initially set to `100px` and transitioned to `200px` when `Show` is clicked.

This almost gives me the desired result in that `#red` slides smoothly when `Show` is clicked ***but not when `Hide` is clicked***. My guess is that `grid-column` does not wait for the transition to complete and I also don't like having to hardcode the values of `width`.

I also tried using `translateX` with transition but once again `grid-column` is set before the transition finishes.

Is there a solution to this problem that uses pure CSS? (I don't mind using JS but it is a last resort and do not want to use anything that involves setTimeout or jQuery.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another class that could take care of the hide transition combined with an `webkitTransitionEnd` event.

Also note that I added a `width: 50%` rather than your fixed width.

```js
const show = document.getElementById('show');
const hide = document.getElementById('hide');
const red = document.getElementById('red');

show.addEventListener('click', function() {
  red.classList.add('expanded');
  red.classList.remove('notexpanded');

});

hide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  red.classList.remove('expanded');
  red.classList.add('notexpanded');
  red.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',
    function(event) {
      red.classList.remove('notexpanded');
    }, false);
});
```

```css
#page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  /* grid-auto-flow: column dense; */
}

#blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-row: 1/span 2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  z-index: 1;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: right;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  /* z-index: -1; cant click hide */
  /* float: right; */
  /* transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 2s; */
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 2s;
}

#red.expanded {
  /* transform: translateX(100%); */
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
}

#red.notexpanded {
  /* transform: translateX(100%); */
  width: 50%;
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id='page'>
  <div id='blue'>
    <button type='button' id='show'>Show</button>
  </div>
  <div id='red'>
    <button type='button' id='hide'>Hide</button>
  </div>
  <div id='yellow'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Islam! That's a nice solution and I wasn't aware of the `webkitTransitionEnd` property. But is there any way that I can avoid having to hardcode the `width`? I would like the grid layout to dictate the dimensions of its contents so that if it changes, I don't have to remember to manually change red's `width`. Also, I'm not sure why `width: 50px;` is needed.

Comment: @user51462 code updated, the `expanded` needs to take full width, and the `notexpanded` half the width. I didn't add a `width: 50px` anywhere :-)

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant `width: 50%;` - but it occurred to me that that is just an arbitrary number to trigger the transition for width. Thank you for your help, it's a really neat solution :) PS In my previous comment, I meant `webkitTransitionEnd` *event*, not property.